# Remover entrada de uma matriz pelo valor da mesma

Tags: php, array

Para remover uma entrada de uma matriz, podemos utilizar a função [unset()](http://pt2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php):

```php
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2);

unset($arr[0]);

var_dump($arr);
/*
Resultado:
array(1) {
  [1]=&gt;
  int(2)
}
*/
?>
```

## Pergunta

Como remover uma entrada de uma matriz pelo seu valor ao invés da sua posição?

<sup>Mediante o exemplo em cima, iríamos passar o valor `1` ao invés da posição `0`.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Para remover um item do array passando o valor, a função [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), resolve. Ela retona a chave caso o valor se encontrado no array e depois basta passar o indice para `unset()`. Essa função não reordena o array.

```php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo'<pre>ANTES';
print_r($arr);

$key = array_search(4, $arr);
unset($arr[$key]);



echo'<pre>DEPOIS';
print_r($arr);
```

saida:

```php
ANTESArray
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)

DEPOISArray
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui pensar em duas formas de fazer isso:

## 1 - Usando `array_search` e `array_values`

Como já respondido pelo `@perdeu` a função `array_search()` resolve o problema de encontrar o valor.

Porém, gostaria de adicionar que a função [`array_values`][1] resolve a questão da reindexação, isto é, ela retorna os valores do array original indexados a partir do zero.

Veja um exemplo:

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    $pos = array_search(2, $array); //buscar posição do segundo elemento
    unset($array[$pos]); //remover elemento
    $array = array_values($array); //recriar índice

A saída final será:

    array(3) {
      [0]=> int(1)
      [1]=> int(3)
      [2]=> int(4)
    }

Veja um exemplo funcional [aqui][2].

# 2 - Usando `array_splice`

Outra alternativa é usar a função [`array_splice()`][3], que permite substituir um trecho de um array por alguma outra coisa, que pode ser *nada*. Esta função altera o array original e recria os índices.

Exemplo:

    $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    $pos = array_search(2, $array); //buscar posição do segundo elemento
    array_splice($array, $pos, 1); //remove 1 elemento na posição encontrada

O resultado é o mesmo citado anteriormente.

Veja o código funcionando [aqui][4].


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php
  [2]: http://codepad.org/at29cKJz
  [3]: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php
  [4]: http://codepad.org/nVQlrXc9