# Remover elemento de array

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Como posso remover apenas um elemento específico do array

```
$produto = Array([0] => Array("ID" => "12", "Nome" => "Produto1", "Valor" => "45,50") [1] => Array("ID" => "13", "Nome" => "Produto2", "Valor" => "45,90"));
```

No caso, o cliente irá informar o Nome ou o ID do array e quero exclui-lo.

Comment: Veja se essa resposta te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27445/removendo-um-elemento-espec%C3%ADfico-em-um-array

Comment: [Remover entrada de uma matriz pelo valor da mesma](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2479/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você pretende remover o Array pelo id ou nome e não pelo index do array você precisa pesquisar este valor e retornar o index dele, o php tem uma função nativa para isto, o `array_search`, depois basta dar unset passando a chave que você recebeu desta função.

**Exemplo:**

```
$produto = array(array("ID" => "12", "Nome" => "Produto1", "Valor" => "45,50"),
    array("ID" => "13", "Nome" => "Produto2", "Valor" => "45,90"));

 $key = array_search('Produto1', $produto); // Encontra index do Produto1

unset($produto[$key]); // Remove do Array

var_dump($produto); // Array sem o indice do Produto1
```

Comment: Amigo, a função array_search não esta trazendo a key que preciso...

Comment: @LucasAugusto da uma debugada na função, ela retorna corretamente o indice, olha  o exemplo executando online: https://ideone.com/EJz69S

Comment: Realmente, funcionou após isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($produto[0])
```

Onde o que está entre colchetes é o índice.

Ou procure pelo valor no array, encontra a chave e remove.

```
$key = array_search($string, $array);
if($key! == false){
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```